# Issue with will_paginate page links

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I currently have a comment model that posts under a micropost and both are displayed on the same page. The issue is that both are displayed on the same page and both are paginated and I am trying to go for the facebook approach to microposting. Here is the issue below:

The links for both pagination turns into this `href="/users/2?page=2"` rather than `href="/users/2/micropost?page=2"` or `href="/users/2/comment?page=2"`. I am unsure how to go about solving this problem. Here are some of my code. All suggestions are much appreciated!

**Micropost Render HTML**

```
<table class="microposts">
<% if microposts.any? %>
<%= render microposts %>
<%= will_paginate microposts, :page_links => false %>
<% else %>
<div class="EmptyContainer"><span class='Empty'>Add a thread!</span></div>
<% end %>
</table>
```

**Comment Section HTML**

```
<div id='CommentContainer-<%= micropost.id%>' class='CommentContainer Condensed2'>
<div class='Comment'>
<%= render :partial => "comments/form", :locals => { :micropost => micropost } %>
</div>
<div id='comments'>
  <% comments = micropost.comments.paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page]) %>
  <%= render comments %>
  <%= will_paginate comments, :class =>"pagination" %>
</div>
</div>
```

**User Controller for the Show Page**

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @micropost = Micropost.new
    @comment = Comment.new
    @comment = @micropost.comments.build(params[:comment])
    @comments = @micropost.comments.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
    @microposts = @user.microposts.order('created_at DESC').paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:page])
      respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
     end
  end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem lies within will_paginate way of creating urls for each page (it doesn't have anything to do with jQuery).

By design, will_paginate try its best to guess what's the base url for the page user is on (internally it's using controller/action to do that). That base url is then combined with any extra params passed to will_paginate helper using `:params` and succesive page numbers.

For now (will_paginate 3.0.3), in order to overwrite this default behavior, you need to write your custom LinkRenderer class. Below there's example of such class - it makes use of new, extra option `:base_link_url` that can be passed to will_paginate view helper. Passed string is then used as a base when creating pagination links. If `:base_link_url` option is not passed, it will fallback to default behavior.

Put following class somewhere rails can find it on load (/lib for example, provided you've added /lib to your autoload paths in `application.rb`):

```
# custom_link_renderer.rb
class CustomLinkRenderer < WillPaginate::ActionView::LinkRenderer
  def prepare(collection, options, template)
    @base_link_url = options.delete :base_link_url
    @base_link_url_has_qs = @base_link_url.index('?') != nil if @base_link_url
    super
  end

  protected
  def url(page)
    if @base_link_url.blank?
      super
    else
      @base_url_params ||= begin
        merge_optional_params(default_url_params)
      end

      url_params = @base_url_params.dup
      add_current_page_param(url_params, page)

      query_s = []
      url_params.each_pair {|key,val| query_s.push("#{key}=#{val}")}

      if query_s.size > 0
        @base_link_url+(@base_link_url_has_qs ? '&' : '?')+query_s.join('&')
      else
        @base_link_url
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
# in your view
will_paginate collection, :renderer => CustomLinkRenderer, :base_link_url => '/anything/you/want'
```

---

And now back to your case. By this time you probably see the solution - you can have two will_paginate widgets on one page with different base urls by passing different `:base_link_url` options for those two.

Comment: I'm assuming for `collection` I replace it with whatever needs to be paginated? Cause if not I am getting an undefined error

Comment: also how would I add the user's id into the base_link_url? Because these two links aren't working `:base_link_url => "/users/<%= user.id%>",` `:base_link_url => "/users/:id",`

Comment: Yes, substitute the `collection` with any other variable holding items to be paginated. As to using :base_link_url option - don't pass the string with some placeholders like you do in routes.rb - just pass there result of url helper method. For example if you have a named route "user_micropost" that is tranlated to (for example) `/user/2/micropost` then `user_micropost_path(:id => 2)` would be the option you need to pass as `:base_link_url`. All links rendered would then get url like: /user/2/micropost?page=1 /user/2/micropost?page=2 and so on.

Comment: Oh and one more thing - `:base_link_url => "/users/<%= user.id%>"` you were almost right there. It should be `:base_link_url => "/users/#{user.id}" though.