# Rails: How to add User ID into a link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have this will_paginate for micropost link and I am trying to add the `<%= user.id %>` into this `base_link_url` but the user.id won't work. Is there a way I can add the user.id into this without receiving an error?

**Link**

`<%= will_paginate microposts, :renderer => CustomLinkRenderer, :base_link_url => "/users/<%= user.id %>", :page_links => false , :class =>"pagination" %>`

For those who are interested where I got this, it is from here:

[Issue with will_paginate page links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563113/issue-with-will-paginate-page-links)

**The Error**

```
/Users/Brian/rails_projects/project/app/views/users/_microposts.html.erb:4: syntax error, unexpected '>'
/Users/Brian/rails_projects/project/app/views/users/_microposts.html.erb:6: syntax error, unexpected keyword_class, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
..._buffer.safe_concat('<div class="EmptyContainer"><span class...
...                               ^
/Users/Brian/rails_projects/project/app/views/users/_microposts.html.erb:6: syntax error, unexpected '<'
...('<div class="EmptyContainer"><span class=\'Empty\'>Add a th...
...                               ^
```

Comment: @rwilliams Your response from before worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try. I don't think that you're properly inserting user.id variable into that statement.

```
<%= will_paginate microposts, :renderer => CustomLinkRenderer, :base_link_url => "/users/#{user.id}", :page_links => false , :class =>"pagination" %>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, I was just unsure how to insert that user.id. Thank you :)